# Como Incrementar um contador dentro do construtor?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, construtor

Olá,

Estou precisando Incrementar um atributo(id) de um Objeto dentro de um Construtor, ou seja, quando eu instanciar um Objeto ele já incrementa o ID daquele objeto.

Eu Criei uma Classe Carro, depois instanciei um novo carro, quando crio o primeiro Objeto vai certo, porem do segundo Objeto em diante, ele não incrementa.

Um pedaço do codigo:

```java
public class Carro {

    public Carro(String marca, String modelo, String cor, String renavam, String placa, int ano) {
        this.codigo++;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.renavam = renavam;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.ano = ano;
    }
```

Comment: *"quando crio o primeiro Objeto vai certo, porem do segundo Objeto em diante, ele não incrementa"* sim porque o construtor cria uma nova instância da classe, um objeto novo, logo não vai incrementar o valor que havia em outro objeto, a não ser que `codigo` fosse o mesmo dentro de multiplas instâncias, se fosse `static` por exemplo, mas isso não seria uma boa forma de tratar isso, o ideal seria que codigo fosse persistido, salvo fora da classe para depois recuperar esse valor e incrementar

Comment: @RicardoPontual muito obrigado mano, entendi o que quis dizer, mas não entendi como faria pra tratar fora da classe. Estou fazendo isso para aprendizado mesmo, desde já, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o comentário do Ricardo Pontual, em uma aplicação de mundo real quem deveria gerenciar a criação deste `id` seria onde essas informações são persistidas, como um banco de dados.

Como você disse que é para estudo, seguindo também o que o Ricardo Pontual disse, você pode usar um atributo `static` que é um atribudo de classe e não de objeto. desta forma você poderia ter algo assim:

```java
public class Carro {
    public static int codigo = 0;
    public Carro(String marca, String modelo, String cor, String renavam, String placa, int ano) {
        // Assim você mantem um contador na classe com código e o valor do id do objeto.
        this.id = Carro.codigo++;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.renavam = renavam;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.ano = ano;
    }
}
```

então caso queria visualizar isso basta imprimir em algum lugar `Carro.codigo`.

**Correção**

Da forma que expliquei ateriormente você teria apenas um contador de objetos, caso você queira que cada objeto tenha seu id e use esse contador para "criar" o próximo id você precisa que o objeto tenha um atributo para armazenar ele também, ajustei o construtor para corrigir o exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Guto, ajudou bastante amigo, eu não cheguei a ver BD ainda pra Java, mas já vi de PHP, então deu pra ter uma noção.

Comment: @BrenoAmador uma correção na minha resposta, vc precisa sim de um atributo id que armazena o id do objeto. vou corrigir a resposta